# Translation of "Yucky!"

Tags: translation, phrase-request

My son has been wondering around Rome and has found quite a few disgusting things to touch.  Is there a good translation of the English phrase "Yucky!", as in "that's gross, don't touch that"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*Schifo!*" means "Gross!". "*Che schifo!*" means "How gross!" I believe this is the closest translation in Italian.

Comment: I don't know the registry of yucky, maybe it can also be said as "bleeeee" (this is not a real word, it's an exclamation)

Comment: @laika I believe "bleee" is more like "ewww"